# jQuery: Read many files in a cycle using the get method

Tags: jquery

I am reading text files using jQuery's GET method inside a cycle. With the information returned, I add some options to a select element. My problem is that sometimes the options add in disorder. My code is the following:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    $.get("./file" + i + ".txt", function(data) {
        $("select").append("<option>" + data + "</option>");
    });
}
```

I am trying to find a solution which does not involve merging all the data in 1 file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: because asynchronous calls will come back at different times. Problem with your design is it is very inefficient to make all those calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is that sometimes the options add in disorder. My code is the following:

**Problem:** it is due to the `async` calls. Your current code just send request to a file and jumps to next iteration, which will send request and jump to next and so on.. You really have no control on when the response will comeback, Also no control to get it in order.

**Solution:** Since you are dealing with `async` process its much better if you use **Recursive function** over the for loop. See below code to understand what I mean.

```js
function GetFile(fileNumber) {
  $.get("./file" + fileNumber + ".txt", function(data) {
    $("select").append("<option>" + data + "</option>");
    fileNumber++;   // since the files was read successfully lets increment the number to next file
    if(fileNumber <= n){ // if we have not reached the limit
        GetFile(fileNumber); // get the next file
    }
  });
}

GetFile(1); //initiate the recursive function by passing the first number
```

Since you have not provided details on what `n` is I have just used it as is in my code too, considering the variable to be available at that scope.

**Explaining the solution:** Create a function that takes a number as input and does a `get` request on the file with the name `"file" + fileNumber + ".txt"` Within the `success` callback of the `get` function I will increment the number and check if its less or equal to the limit `n` If it is less or equal then I go ahead and call the same function by passing the new number. This will continue until we have reached the limit.

**Note:** The above logic stops if there is an error in any of the request. If you however want to continue even if there are error in the response,  Then you can add the `.fail()` handler.. See below.

```
  $.get("./file" + fileNumber + ".txt", function(data) {
    //above shown logic
  }).fail(function() {
     console.log("There was an error while fetching file"+fileNumber +".txt");
     fileNumber++;
     if(fileNumber <= n){ // see if next file exist
       console.log("Processing next file!!");
       GetFile(fileNumber); // get the next file
     }
   });
```